# Setting and installing JAVA_HOME and apache_NiFi on an EC2 instance using ansible- not working

Tags: ansible, apache-nifi, java-home

I am a newbie to ansible and I am trying to set and install JAVA_HOME and NiFi via ansible on a node running RHEL7. I run the following playbook:

```
---
- hosts: web
  sudo: yes
  environment:
    JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64/jre
  tasks:
  - name: Creates directory
    file: path=/home/ec2-user/nifi state=directory

  - name: Download NiFi
    get_url:
      url: http://archive.apache.org/dist/nifi/1.5.0/nifi-1.5.0-bin.zip
      dest: /home/ec2-user/nifi/nifi.zip

  - name: install unzip
    yum:
      name: unzip
      state: present

  - name: Extract NiFi in the same folder
    unarchive:
      src: /home/ec2-user/nifi/nifi.zip
      dest: /home/ec2-user/nifi/
      copy: no


  - name: configure the webserver in nifi.properties file
    replace:
      dest: /home/ec2-user/nifi/nifi-1.5.0/conf/nifi.properties
      regexp: 'nifi.web.http.host='
      replace: 'nifi.web.http.host=ec2-13-211-204-235.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com'

  - name: install java
    yum:
      name: java-1.8.0-openjdk
      state: present

  - name: start NiFi
    shell: /home/ec2-user/nifi/nifi-1.5.0/bin/nifi.sh start
    register: shell_out

  - debug:
      var: shell_out
```

Basically the code above includes these tasks: setting JAVA_HOME, create a directory for nifi, download nifi, extract nifi, install java and run nifi. The output of the shell below shows that nifi is installed and JAVA_HOME is set and everything seems ok:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [13.211.204.235] => {
    "shell_out": {
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": "/home/ec2-user/nifi/nifi-1.5.0/bin/nifi.sh start", 
        "delta": "0:00:04.023438", 
        "end": "2018-04-11 05:46:13.735321", 
        "failed": false, 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2018-04-11 05:46:09.711883", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stderr_lines": [], 
        "stdout": "\nJava home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64/jre\nNiFi home: /home/ec2-user/nifi/nifi-1.5.0\n\nBootstrap Config File: /home/ec2-user/nifi/nifi-1.5.0/conf/bootstrap.conf", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "", 
            "Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64/jre", 
            "NiFi home: /home/ec2-user/nifi/nifi-1.5.0", 
            "", 
            "Bootstrap Config File: /home/ec2-user/nifi/nifi-1.5.0/conf/bootstrap.conf"
        ]
    }
}
```

When I check EC2 instance, all the changes have been applied e.g., extraction of downloaded file in the folder and nifi.properties configuration. However, when I check the nifi status there is no nifi running on the instance. In addition, the value of JAVA_HOME is null when I run `echo $JAVA_HOME` in bash.

**To add more info:**
I have checked the log file on the instance and it seems nifi starts and quickly stops after:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-8-240 logs]$ cat nifi-app.log 
2018-04-11 07:06:09,698 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Launching NiFi...
2018-04-11 07:06:10,175 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader Determined default nifi.properties path to be '/home/ec2-user/nifi/nifi-1.5.0/./conf/nifi.properties'
2018-04-11 07:06:10,178 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader Loaded 144 properties from /home/ec2-user/nifi/nifi-1.5.0/./conf/nifi.properties
2018-04-11 07:06:10,200 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Loaded 144 properties
2018-04-11 07:06:10,209 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Started Bootstrap Listener, Listening for incoming requests on port 33327
2018-04-11 07:06:10,233 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Successfully initiated communication with Bootstrap
2018-04-11 07:06:10,257 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarUnpacker Expanding 89 NAR files with all processors...
2018-04-11 07:06:12,710 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
2018-04-11 07:06:12,710 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Jetty web server shutdown completed (nicely or otherwise).
```

Comment: I have added more details to my previous question.

Answer (score 1):

Every task runs in its own process.

To properly set it you need to use `environment` for the whole play, eg:

```
- hosts: xxx
  roles: []
  environment:
    JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64/jre
```

or on per-task basis using the same syntax.

References:

- http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html